# Why can´t I lanch this ros .launch file from a .desktop file in Ubuntu properly?

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-application, ros

I need to launch a ros .launch file from a desktop application, but this is doing nothing for some reason. Any help?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=LaunchMagnobit
Comment=Launch tracker and controller
Exec="roslaunch mbx_launch mbx_ros_tracker_camera.launch"
Icon=/home/magnebotix/Pictures/ps3.jpg
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories==Application;
```

Answer (score 0):

When running ros nodes you always need to make sure that your correct environments are sourced; this won’t be the case running it directly in a desktop file. Instead of running the command directly you want to Exec a custom bash script that sources your env correctly. For example:

```
source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
roslaunch mbx_launch mbx_ros_tracker_camera.launch
```